# añadir color a un campo String android

Tags: java, android, string, color

Buenas tengo un campo String que necesito añadirle un color pero no he podido lograr hacerlo, aqui les dejo mi codigo.
lo que sucede es que al titulo le anticipo texto de la db y por eso lo realizo asi de manera q add se le agregaria al textview.

```
private String add = null;
ItemDisplayList appointment = mItems.get(position);
add = appointment.getmNombre_empresa();
```

Comment: quieres agregarle color a un Textview??

Comment: el color se le asigna al elemento donde lo muestres, no al string. El textView puede tener color con la propiedad `TextView.setTextColor(color);`

Comment: Te sugiero seas más especifico, incluso puedes agregar una imagen de lo que deseas.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres agregarle color a un `TextView` puedes utilizar

```
tuTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

**EDIT**

Si lo que deseas es separar el texto en colores como dices, pueden haber dos opciones:

1) Separar titulos de valores. Con esto me refiero a tener otro `TextView` en tu vista uno con el titulo por ejemplo Nombre y otro `TextView` con el valor y el color que deseas.

2) Setear asi los valores

```
String texto = "<font color=#000000>Titulo color defecto</font> <font color=#ff0000>Valor con segundo color</font>";
tuTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(texto));
```

Comment: lo que pasa es que no quiero agregarle color a todo el textview solo a la parte que le agrego es decir un nombre de la persona en color que es el add y depues el color default al titulo

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega eso, que así no se entiende que es lo que quieres.

Comment: Deberian ser elementos distintos, un label para el titulo y ese color por defecto y otro para el dato, que lo quieres en rojo

Comment: no sé si sea viable @sioesi pero el OP menciona en la pregunta que quiere cambiarle color a un String, cosa que no se puede hacer. ¿Puedes aclararlo en la respuesta?

Comment: actualice mi respuesta! @L.Ronquillo

Comment: @L.Ronquillo ok amigo, bueno pues preguntaba por lo mismo para saber si es posible

Comment: @sioesi gracias amigo me ayudo tu respuesta

Comment: +1 :) @JoseeNaava no olvides marcar la Respuesta como aceptada :)

Comment: @L.Ronquillo valee

Comment: @JoseeNaava que bueno que haya funcionado!, recuerda marcarla :D